# Setting subscriptions on multiple microsoft graph objects

Tags: rest, api, microsoft-graph-api

With Microsoft Graph, I can set a subscription on a resource.  In my case an event.  I am going to be using an admin authenticated account to access multiple calendars.
Is there a way to set a subscription to get notifications on all the calendars the admin can see?
If not, is there a way to send in a block of subscriptions with a single request?  Because we are limited to how many requests we can specify in a specific timeframe. (I'm not sure what the limit is) but if I have 500 calendars I need to set subscriptions on so I get notifications of changes, how are you supposed to do this and not get hit by the request per timeframe limit?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a way to send multiple subscription creation requests in the same HTTP REST call. Every different resource for which a subscription is being created would have its own HTTP call into the Graph REST API.

You can recommend a "batching" feature (so multiple REST requests can be processed in the same HTTP call to the Graph API) on UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a consideration that, in my experience, the number of simultaneous subscriptions allowed is around 20, so 500 subscriptions might be out of the question.  The best advice I've been given on the subject is to loop through all the objects one at a time to refresh them in sequence.  The throttling that follows is a different issue altogether.

When a 429/"Unknown Error" comes back (ie throttling), it comes with a retry-after header which should be observed.  I might point out that throttling, for me, is still a huge issue.

Comment: Is there any documentation listing the 20 subscription limit that you know of? I have looked to no avail. Seems like that limit would just about make these webhooks pointless...

Comment: There does seem to be a lack of documentation on the topic.. thought I had seen something but no luck now.  While I don't want to discourage you from trying yourself, I recall hitting that limit right around 20 subscriptions.  There is always the possibility I was doing something wrong, though.